# JavaScript form input

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I was wondering if anybody knows how to use the code below to make it so that if the input contains an item of the javascript array it will redirect the page using window.location.href? Here is the code I have currently:

```
  var x = ["1", "2", "3"];


              function validateForm() {
                var x = document.forms["myForm"]["value"].value;
                if (x != "59864") {
                  alert("doesnt contain");
                  return false;
                }


                var x = document.forms["myForm"]["value"].value;
                if (x == "59864") {
                  window.location.href = "index.php";

                  return false;
                }


              }
```

Comment: What doesn't work with the code at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use indexof method to check if any of the input matches with an array value.

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["value"].value;
if(yourArray.indexOf(x) != -1)
{
window.location.href = "index.php";
return false;
}
```